# The 'Thumbnail' attribute has no file associated with it. Django {% if %} {% else%} {% endif %}

Tags: python, html, django

The 'Thumbnail' attribute has no file associated with it.

I have tried Django {% if %} {% else %} {% endif %} in my HTML list and it works on the page, but when I do the same for a detailview HTML it doesn't work and returns "The 'Thumbnail' attribute has no file associated with it."

** Models.py **

```
class Article(models.Model):
   Title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
   Thumbnail = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
   Author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   Content = QuillField()
   Date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
   slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='Title')
```

** Views.py**

```
class ArticlesDetailView(DetailView):
   model = Article
   template_name = 'articles_app/articles_detail.html'

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      latest = Article.objects.order_by('-id')[0:3]
      context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['latest'] = latest
      return context
```

** HTML - List (articles_list.html) ** It works perfectly fine here!!!

```
<img src=" {% if articles.Thumbnail %} 
{{ articles.Thumbnail.url }} 
{% else %} 
{% static 'img/add-ons/article_thumbnail_default.jpg' %} 
{% endif %} " alt="..." class="card-img-top">
```

** HTML - Detail (articles_detail.html) ** It doesn't work here.

```
{% for obj in latest %} 

<img src="{% if obj.Thumbnail %} 
{{ obj.Thumbnail.url }} 
{% else %} 
{% static 'img/add-ons/article_thumbnail_default.jpg' %} 
{% endif %} " alt="..." class="card-img-top">

{% endfor %}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: You might be trying to access the attribute somewhere else also.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get the latest 3 articles on each article detail page.

Answer (score 0):

try `object.Thumbnail` instead of `obj.Thumbnail`, I think that will solve your problem.

Comment: I have tried a lot of variations and it still doesn't work. What's bothering me is that my if/else works in my articles list page but when I go to my article details page I have a section that shows the latest 3 posts and the thumbnail is not getting through with the if/else. So I have to get rid of if/else and make image mandatory in my models which I already did because I'm running out of time.